# Is it possible to have few object factories when trying to work with JAXB?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I have two sets of generated java classes (every set have corresponding ObjectFactory) and I want to merge them in one set to use simultaneously.

Is it possible to work with two **ObjectFactories** (two classes marked as **@XmlRegistry**) in JAXB?

Classes were generated by

maven-jaxb2-plugin (version 0.8.3)

JDK: 1.6.0_43

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working with Two `ObjectFactory` Classes

Yes you can work with multiple `ObjectFactory` classes.  In your code you will need to package qualify at least one of the references.  The class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` does not need to be called `ObjectFactory` but the one generated by JAXB from an XML Schema always is.

### Can JAXB Merge the `ObjectFactory` Classes

No, for the following reasons:

1. It introduces possible method name conflicts that JAXB would then have to provide a conflict resolution mechanism for.
2. When a `JAXBContext` is created on one or more package names it looks for an `ObjectFactory` class in that package to derive metadata from.  Reducing the number of `ObjectFactory` classes would break this.
3. Ultimately it wouldn't make your code any easier.

### Can You Merge Them Manually

Yes.  You just need to be mindful that if you're creating a `JAXBContext` by package name(s) that your `ObjectFactory` gets picked up.